# How to return lIEnumerable list

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

i am new to programming and i got stuck. I am not very sure how to return my list. Can someone help now i get only System.IEnumerable and if i try to use foreach i cant iterate over the Employee

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return new List<Employee> 
            {
               new Employee { Name = "Tom", Id = 1 },
               new Employee { Name = "Peter", Id = 3 },
               new Employee { Name = "Michael", Id = 2 }
            };
        }




    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var employee = new Employee();



           
            foreach(var emp in Employee)
            {

            }
        }
     
    }
```

Comment: foreach(var emp in Employee.GetEmployees())

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
IEnumerable<Employee> ls = emp.GetEmployees();

foreach( Employee e in ls)
{

}
```

Comment: thank you and how to do it if i want only employee with id 2?

Comment: `Employee e = emp.GetEmployees().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);`

Comment: Also I want to add that it would more sense to make the `GetEmployees` method static as it doesn’t really make sense that you need to create an (empty) Employee instance just to get the list of all employees.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop, you forgot to invoke your method GetEmployees. You need to do it if you want to iterate over it.

`foreach(var emp in Employee.GetEmployees())`